# How to get the changed file names between two consecutive git pull?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-diff

I am trying to get the names of files that have been changed in 2 consecutive pull requests. So 2 developers have changed 2 diff files and pushed to github. When i try to pull it in 3rd repo i need to get the 2 changed filenames. Currently i am getting only the changed file name of the latest developer by using the following code.

```
git diff --diff-filter=ACMR --name-only @{1}..
```

If anyone have any idea please share.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Two different Pull request means two different branch.

```
 $ git fetch 
 $ git diff <branch1>..<branch2> --name-only   # changed file name
```